# Ge-76 Double beta decay

Tags: radiation

Is the process ${^{76}Ge} \rightarrow {^{76}Se}^{--} + \nu_{e} + \nu_{e} + e^{+} + e^{+}$ possible?

In my opinion this process is not possible because it violates the charge conservation and the leptonic number conservation.

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_beta_decay